# Listen to specific port

Tags: networking, mac, iphone, port

I have 2 devices (mac and an iphone), which I have programs running on that are communicating on a certain port. Is there a program that will be able to "listen in" in the ports? I have downloaded Charles Proxy but it only seems to catch web traffic.

Or even have a computer in between the mac and the iphone, that can see what happening between the two devices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is an excellent cross-platform program that you could use to capture the traffic between these two devices. You can specify within WireShark's capture settings to listen on specific ports or traffic from specific addresses. This would have to be on the Mac, unless both the Mac and the iPhone were using a wireless connection or a hub (**not** a switch/router) (if so, you could use any computer connected to that access point/hub).